# Bootstrap 4 navbar-expand-[sm | md | lg | xl] not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

We have a navbar generated from a controller (as we don't know how many links it will have, it has to be dynamic) and want to adjust the collapse point. In older versions of bootstrap it took a mammoth amount of javascript but I gather with version 4 we should be able to set using 'navbar-expand-*' but whatever this is set to is still collapses at 768px.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-expand-xl" id="secureNavbar">
```

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: `navbar-expand-xl` should collapse at 1200px width, `-lg` at 992px, `-md` at 768px, `-sm` at 576px. problem might be `navbar-fixed-top`